# Different ways of class Initialization in C#

Tags: c#

Generally in C# classes are Initialized as shown below.

```
Class_name cs= new Class_name();
```

But in some cases like it is done differently. Can anyone brief about it.

Example :

```
DataTable custTable = new DataTable(); // Class DataTable Initialization

DataRow row1 = custTable.NewRow();
```

The way DataRow class Initialized is different can any one explain this kind.

Comment: Usually convenience.  Sometimes in a parent child relationship for example, some setup/navigation/build needs to happen.

Comment: What's the difference between `int i = 1;`, `int i = 5 - 4;`, and `int i = GetNumberFromDatabase();`? That's more or less what's happening here. Just different ways to _create_ something. Sometimes, the result is the same and sometimes it's different. It's as simple as that.

Comment: `NewRow` is a *method* of the `DataTable` class. This method executes `new DataRow()`, but does other things as well (like making sure the DataRow knows about the DataTable's columns). Then, a reference to this data row is returned and you assign it to your `row1` variable.

Comment: `Class_name cs= new Class_name;` I don't believe that this is actually valid and should be `Class_name cs= new Class_name();`

Comment: I wouldn't call it convenience but slightly different. Its about least knowledge about how to get something without the need to know all the details. If you would be left alone with that you might break the system. So some kind of factory pattern is applied to get objects. For example you could be getting classes inherited from DataRow here instead of a DataRow because of context. And maybe because of context you don't need to know of because of complexity not relevant to the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are *always* initialized with the `new` keyword and a constructor.

```
MyClass x = new MyClass();
MyClass y = new MyClass(1,2,3);
MyClass z = new MyClass(x);
```

Now it is possible the initialization is inside a method of another class, or a static method of your class. Regardless, the `new` keyword is still used inside the class.

There is nothing stopping you from creating code like this in order to control who can call the constructor.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Class() { }
    static MyClass Create()
    {
        return new MyClass();
    }
}

MyClass x = MyClass.Create();
```

With the above code the only way a consumer of `MyClass` can create an instance is through the `Create()` method.

A similar pattern is common where a class is initialized from another class

```
public class Simulation
{
    public Results Calculate(Conditions cond)
    {
        return new Results(this, cond);
    }
}

public class Results
{
    public Result(Simulation sim, Conditions cond)
    {
    }
}

Simulation sim = new Simulation();
Conditions cond = new Conditions();
Results r = sim.Calculate(cond);
```

Answer (score 1):

Easier example, using `string`

```
string a = "first"; // from literal
string b = MakeMessage(); // from method
string c = new string("third"); // from constructor

string MakeMessage()
{
    return new string("second");
}
```

Even though string are immutable, this is essentially the same thing (other than the literal).

A constructor (`new string()`) is a method. All you're doing is executing a method and saving the result to a variable.

Sometimes authors of an API will choose not to allow the constructor to be public, and thus the only way to construct an object is with static methods or a method from a "parent" object.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `custTable.NewRow()` is a simply way to create and add a new DataRow to your table ('custTable'), being this DataRow equals to all other DataTable rows (same colums f.e. I mean). You cannot create `new DataRow()` because you need to have this DataRow associated to a DataTable scheme, in order to have all DataRows in same DataTable with same properties (columns, f.e.).

Hope this was clear!